# erb block not looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iterator, erb

I'm trying to generate results for a webstore using this erb block and I want 4 images per row, but right now it is only generating one image per row. Any advice would be highly appreciated

```
<% n = 4 %> 
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<div class="row-fluid"> 
<% if (n%4 == 0) %>
<% end %>
  <div class="span3">
    <%= link_to image_tag(product.images.order(:placement).first.image.url(:medium)), product if product.images.present? %>
    <p class="text-center"><%= link_to product.name, product %></p>
  </div>
  <% if (n%4 == 3) %>
<% end %>
<% n += 1 %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby will break it into groups of four for you using [Enumerable#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
<% @products.each_slice(4) do |row| %>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <% row.each do |product| %>
      <div class="span3">
        <%= link_to image_tag(product.images.order(:placement).first.image.url(:medium)), product if product.images.present? %>
        <p class="text-center"><%= link_to product.name, product %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```